# Game crashes when two objects of same class collide libgdx

Tags: libgdx, box2d

I have a class named Meteor and I created a function that create Meteors all the time, and I have a Player class.

The collision between the Player and Meteor works fine, but the game crashes when a collision between two meteors occurs.

I don't know why the crash occurs and I want to fix it.

Meteor Class

```
public class Meteor  {

String[] meteorNames = new String[]{"meteorBrown_big1", "meteorBrown_big2", "meteorBrown_big3",
        "meteorBrown_big4", "meteorBrown_med3", "meteorGrey_big1", "meteorGrey_big2",
        "meteorGrey_big3", "meteorGrey_big4", "meteorGrey_med2"};

HashMap<String, Sprite> map;
    World world;
    public Body body;
    public Sprite meteorSprite;
    String name;
    public Boolean destroyed = false;

public Meteor(World world, HashMap<String, Sprite> map){

    this.world = world;
    this.map = map;
    Random random = new Random();
    name = meteorNames[random.nextInt(meteorNames.length)];
    meteorSprite = map.get(name);
    defineMeteor();

}

public void drawMeteor(SpriteBatch batch){
    if(!isDestroyed()){
        meteorSprite.setPosition(body.getPosition().x, body.getPosition().y);
        meteorSprite.setRotation((float) Math.toDegrees(body.getAngle()));
        meteorSprite.setOrigin(0, 0);
        meteorSprite.draw(batch);
    }

}

private void defineMeteor(){

    BodyEditorLoader loader = new BodyEditorLoader(Gdx.files.internal("data/meteors/meteors.json"));
    //Create the body
    BodyDef bodyDef =  new BodyDef();

    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;

    bodyDef.position.set(100, 200);

    //Set the physics properties
    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.density = 4 * meteorSprite.getWidth();
    fixtureDef.restitution = 0.6f;
    fixtureDef.friction = 0.2f;

    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    //Random location to create a meteor in x axis
    Random r1 = new Random();

    int High = (int) ( Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.5);
    int Low = (int) (-Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * 0.5);
    int r2 = r1.nextInt(High - Low) + Low;
    //body.setTransform(r2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.5f, 0);
    body.setTransform(0, 50 * 0.5f, 0);
    body.setUserData(Meteor.this);

    //Random Vx and Vy
    r1 = new Random();
    r2 = r1.nextInt(3);
    r1 = new Random();
    int r3 = r1.nextInt(40);
    body.setLinearVelocity(0, -r3);
    body.setAngularVelocity(-r2);

    loader.attachFixture(body, name + ".png", fixtureDef, meteorSprite.getWidth());

    //Create sensor
    fixtureDef.isSensor = true;
    FixtureDef fDef = fixtureDef;
    fDef.isSensor = true;
    fDef.filter.categoryBits = MyGdxGame.METEOR_BIT;
    fDef.filter.maskBits = MyGdxGame.SHIP_BIT | MyGdxGame.METEOR_BIT;
    loader.attachFixture(body, name + ".png", fDef, meteorSprite.getWidth());
    //body.getFixtureList().get(body.getFixtureList().size-1).setUserData("meteorSensor");


}

public void setToDestroy(){
    destroyed = true;
}

public Boolean isDestroyed(){
    return destroyed;
}
```

ContactLisneter Class

```
public class ContactGameListener implements com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.ContactListener {

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {

    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

    int cDef = fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits | fixB.getFilterData().categoryBits;


    switch (cDef){
        case MyGdxGame.SHIP_BIT | MyGdxGame.METEOR_BIT:
            if(fixA.getFilterData().categoryBits == MyGdxGame.SHIP_BIT){
                ((Player)fixA.getBody().getUserData()).life -=1;
                ((Player)fixA.getBody().getUserData()).score +=1;
            }

            else {
                ((Player)fixB.getBody().getUserData()).life -=1;
                ((Player)fixB.getBody().getUserData()).score +=1;
            }
            break;
        case MyGdxGame.METEOR_BIT | MyGdxGame.METEOR_BIT:
            Gdx.app.log("Meteoro", "meteoro");
            fixA.getBody().setTransform(fixA.getBody().getPosition().x, fixA.getBody().getPosition().y, fixA.getBody().getAngle());
            fixB.getBody().setTransform(fixB.getBody().getPosition().x, fixB.getBody().getPosition().y, fixB.getBody().getAngle());
            break;

    }
```

Error found

```
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI CallVoidMethodV called with pending exception 'java.lang.ClassCastException' thrown in unknown throw location
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]     in call to CallVoidMethodV
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]     from void com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.jniStep(long, float, int, int)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70] "GLThread 67293" prio=5 tid=14 Runnable
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   at com.badlogic.gdx.physics.box2d.World.step(World.java:689)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   at com.mygdx.game.libgdx.Screens.GameScreen.stepWorld(GameScreen.java:248)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   at com.mygdx.game.libgdx.Screens.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:139)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
A/art: art/runtime/check_jni.cc:70]   at com.mygdx.game.libgdx.Screens.MyGdxGame.render(MyGdxGame.java:101)
```

MyGdxGame.java:101:

```
@Override
    public void render() {
        super.render(); //101
    }
```

GameScreen.java:248:

```
world.step(STEP_TIME, VELOCITY_ITERATIONS, POSITION_ITERATIONS); // 248
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When two meteors collide you set the transform of each body to the transform of the colliding fixtures, I am not sure why you would want to do that or what you hope to achieve.

Regardless, you're not allowed to mutate the state of the bodies or fixtures while the `World` step is being executed, which it still is when the contact listener call-back fires. You need to perform such actions outside the call to `step`.

Comment: Thanks to your response I could fix it, I remove all the `.setTransform` from the code, even in the Meteor.class.I added the follow `if` statment to check twice my fixtures objects `if(ship.getBody().getUserData().getClass().equals(Player.class))` and works fine